# In Python, how can I get dates to format properly?

Tags: python, date, format

I'm trying to turn a datetime, taken from a CSV file, and parse it into it's component date and time aspects. '11/06/2017 17:59' should become '11/06/2017' and '17:59' respectively.

What I've got so far is:

```
Date = datetime.strptime(row['Date'],"$m/%d/%y %H:%M")
Date = datetime.strftime(oldDate, "%m/%d/%Y")
Time = datetime.strftime(oldDate, "%H:%M")
```

when I run it though it errors out saying "ValueError: time data '11/06/2017 17:59' does not match format '$m/%d/%y %H:%M'" That looks like it is the same format. Am I missing something?

Comment: `$m` should be `%m`.

Comment: `%y` should be `%Y`.

Comment: Replace that dollar with a percent.

Comment: yeah, I'm blind >_< I can see missing the capitalized Y but the dollar sign makes me feel like an idiot.

Comment: All the datetime directive are very nicely explained in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format is `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M` (note, no `$`, the `Y` is capitalised to indicate 4 digit year format).

```
In [4]: datetime.strptime('11/06/2017 17:59',"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 6, 17, 59)
```

For more information on various legal datetime formats, visit the [`datetime` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

---

For your second bit, use `dt.date` and `dt.time` to grab individual components.

```
In [5]: d.date()
Out[5]: datetime.date(2017, 11, 6)

In [6]: d.time()
Out[6]: datetime.time(17, 59)
```

You can call `str` on the result after, for a human readable output.